# How do I login with linq to twitter?

Tags: .net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm sorry if its obvious but I cant find the answer. I want to post a status. All I can find are these two lines. I can't figure out how to login. I don't care if its a user/password or if its using an API key.

```
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext();
var tweet = twitterCtx.UpdateStatus(@"test text");
```

I'm doing this this as a console app.

Comment: After a lot of pain and various .NET twitter wrappers i ended up grabbing nuget package manager http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c and installing tweetsharp from there.

Comment: Linq-to-twitter?  Only 140 characters allowed in the code?  Try the TwitterContext(UsernamePasswordAuthorization) constructor instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: I see no documentation on that. But i got this working with tweetsharp and with mono/linux

Comment: I see some refering to tweetsharp. Just want to point out the I believe Linq2Twitter is much better, has more clean and understandable code, does not have what seems to be bugs and missing features

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about my English but I'll Try to help you!

First you need to create an authentication one way is with your user and password of your own twitter count.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthorization cxauthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthorization();
ctxauthenticatin.UserName = userName; // Put in your Twitter Account
ctxauthenticatin.Password = password; // and password
ctxauthenticatin.AllowUIPrompt = false;
ctxauthenticatin.SignOn();

var ctxTwitterContext = new TwitterContext(ctxauthentication);
ctxTwitterContext.UpdateStatus("test text");
```

There is another way, where you need to register an aplication in twitter in this page http://dev.twitter.com here you register an aplicattion put in a name, a direccion of your web, then they give you a ConsumerKey,ConsumerSecert and if you clic in generate Access Token then also they give you an AccessToken, and AccessTokenSecret. Remenber go to Setting and select the option  Read, Write and Access direct messages. and then generate the AccessToken. Ok with this in your code you do something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private WebAuthorizer auth;
private TwitterContext twitterCtx;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IOAuthCredentials credentials = new SessionStateCredentials();

    if (credentials.ConsumerKey == null || credentials.ConsumerSecret == null)
    {
        credentials.ConsumerKey = "Here put your ConsumerKey";
        credentials.ConsumerSecret = "Here put your ConsumerSecret"
    }

    auth = new WebAuthorizer
    {
        Credentials = credentials,
        PerformRedirect = authUrl => Response.Redirect(authUrl)
    };
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url);
    }
     twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
 }
protected void authorizeTwitterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    auth.BeginAuthorization(Request.Url);
}
```

protected void SendTweet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             twitterCtx.UpdateStatus("My Test Tweet");
    }

Easy!! Ok how it's works! first when you clic the button authorizeTwitterButton, you begin the authorizarion for your twitter account and new window will open with the log in of twitter you authorize the aplication and then twitter redirect to your page with the credentials necesary so then when you clic the send button you post a new tweet!

Also there is another way where you dont need to use the begin and complete authorization methods. Here you introduce directly all the credential. for example:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey = "your ConsumerKey",
                ConsumerSecret = "Your consumerSecret",
                OAuthToken = "your AccessToken",
                AccessToken = "your AccessTokenSecret"]
            }
        };
var ctxTwitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);
ctxTwitterContext.UpdateStatus("test text");
```

Ok! I hope my anwser help you!! for more information visit the documentation in http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/
Bye! if you like my anwser just give me a click!! jaja

Comment: This is an old question and in the comments i already said i got something working. But +1 anyways

Comment: I like tweetsharp better. https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp#authenticating-a-client-application-ie-desktop. After i put in the app consumer key/secret the little code takes no effort for a user to authorize their account.